# How to Avoid Temporary Website's server sleeping

Tags: server, web, sleep, temporary

I have a webApplication (Asp.net C#) and i need to send some data to another WebService at about 8:00am by my webApplication.

I used Timer class(static variable), timer's Elapsed(EventHandler) and interval(about 20min) to check hour and send data at 8:00am to WebService.

Every thing is good, and Timer's event handler run good.
but, after 2 hour if my website didnt have any request and Traffic, website will be sleep temporary! so timer and other static variable will be lost !! and task failed temporary!

---

Then, if one user send request to Visit the website, WebApplication will start again and timer and other Static variables will active!

---

if we haven't any visit or request, can we Avoid this Temporary Website's server sleeping?